# Hiding the domain of a HTML page in address bar

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Suppose you open an HTML page on web it has url like :
**https://storage.googleapis.com/fasdcjh-jdfsdf/ga/123/test.html**

I want to put some javascript in **test.html** so that the url changes to
*lkasdjhfklahsdfklasjdflahfd*  (some random string)
The **test.html** is my creation so i can modify it to achieve it.

what i tried :
Insert this script in the html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.replaceState(null,'title','asdakjsdhjkad');
    </script>
```

It changed the url to  - **https://storage.googleapis.com/fasdcjh-jdfsdf/asdakjsdhjk**

**So the last part did got changed. But the domain storage.googleapis.com and the rest of the string in path didnt.**
How to achieve that ?

PS:
The HTML files will be uploaded to a google cloud storage account.
The above script worked when accessing the document from the google cloud storage but only hiding the last part

Comment: You cannot change the domain part of a URL without changing to that domain

Comment: okay. But just to be clear. I just want the url in address bar to change and not jump to that url. If i was jumping to that url then its clear that i cannot change the domain. But can i change it and stay on the same page ?

Comment: Try : window.history.replaceState(null,'title','/asdakjsdhjkad');
This modified url to  https://storage.googleapis.com/asdakjsdhjkad

Try this :  history.replaceState(null,"title",'https://www.techiedelight.com/');
This does try to change the whole url but with following error : 

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://www.techiedelight.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://storage.googleapis.com' and URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/www.google.com'.
    at <anonymous>:1:9